# Enable and disable check boxes using ng-disabled

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I got a list of check box + labels. If you check the first one, all the checkbox (except the first one) have to be disabled. The problem is that if I uncheck the first checkbox, all the others are still disabled and I want them to be enable again.

**JS**

```
<li ng-repeat="ques in questions">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="addRemove(ques)" ng-checked="contains(ques) != -1" ng-disabled="noneSelected && $index != 0"/> {{ques.question}}
</li>
```

**controller**

```
 if (ques.question == "None") {
            var index = $scope.contains(ques);
            if (index != -1) {
                $scope.noneSelected = false;
                $rootScope.selectedQuestions.splice(index, 1);
            } else {
                $scope.noneSelected = true;
                $rootScope.selectedQuestions = [];
                $rootScope.selectedQuestions.push(ques);
            }
 }
```

**SOLUTION**

In the rest of the code, I was doing some sutff on `selectedQuestions` array. It was causing some troubles.

Comment: Is that code from the controller what gets called in the ng-click?

Comment: yes, this is the function "addRemove(ques)"

Comment: Can you show me your `questions` array values?

Comment: They are from database
It contains an ID, question (which is text), description (text too)

Comment: My first guess is that the noneSelected property is not being defined on the correct scope, but not sure how that is happening.

Comment: I think it is, because I can disable all the checkbox... I just can't enable them again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see rest of your code but please see demo below:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('homeCtrl', homeCtrl);

homeCtrl.inject = ['$scope']

function homeCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.questions = [{
    question: "what"
  }, {
    question: "when"
  }, {
    question: "who"
  }]


};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="homeCtrl">

  <li ng-repeat="ques in questions">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="questions[0].val && $index>0" ng-model="ques.val" />{{ques.question}} {{question.val}}
  </li>
</body>

</html>
```